# How to test sendgrid email with mailtrap for testing?

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel 7.6 app I use sendgrid for email sending with code in control like :

```
  \Mail
    ::to($newContactUs->author_email)->
   send(new SendgridMail('emails/contact_us_was_sent', $newContactUs->author_email, '', $subject, $additiveVars, $attachFiles));
```

with class in app/Mail/SendgridMail.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Sichikawa\LaravelSendgridDriver\SendGrid;
use App\Settings;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;

class SendgridMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    use SendGrid;
    use funcsTrait;

    private  $m_view_name;
    private  $m_to;
    private  $m_cc;
    private  $m_subject;
    private  $m_additiveVars;
    private  $m_attachFiles;

    public function __construct( $view_name, $to= [], $cc= '', $subject= '', $additiveVars= [], $attachFiles= [] )
    {
        $this->m_view_name= $view_name;
        $this->m_to= $to;
        $this->m_cc= $cc;
        $this->m_subject= $subject;
        $all_emails_copy      =   \Config::get('app.all_emails_copy');

        if ( empty($this->m_cc) and !empty($all_emails_copy)) {
            $this->m_cc= $all_emails_copy;
        }


        $additiveVars['site_home_url']         = \URL::to('/');
        $additiveVars['site_name']             = Settings::getValue('site_name');
        $additiveVars['noreply_email']         = Settings::getValue('noreply_email');
        $additiveVars['support_signature']     = Settings::getValue('support_signature');
        $additiveVars['medium_slogan_img_url'] = config('app.url').config('app.medium_slogan_img_url');

        $this->m_additiveVars= $additiveVars;
        $this->m_attachFiles= $attachFiles;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build( )
    {
        $mailObject= $this
            ->view( $this->m_view_name)
            ->subject($this->m_subject)
            ->to([$this->m_to])
            ->cc([$this->m_cc])
            ->with( $this->m_additiveVars )
            ->sendgrid( $this->m_additiveVars );
        foreach( $this->m_attachFiles as $next_attach_file) {
            if ( file_exists($next_attach_file) ) {
                $mailObject->attach($next_attach_file);
            }
        }
        return $mailObject;
    }

}
```

and template resources/views/emails/contact_us_was_sent.blade.php:

```
...
<div class="wrapper">
    @inject('viewFuncs', 'App\library\viewFuncs')


    <h4 class="email_title">
        Hello, {!! $to_user_name !!} !
    </h4>
    ...

    @include( 'emails.app_footer')
    @include( 'emails.emails_style')
</div>
```

and it works for me now, but now with "Multiple Mail Drivers" I added mailtrap to my .env :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=NNNNNNNN
MAIL_PASSWORD=NNNNNNNN
```

and I want to use mailtrap while testing the app using the same 
template resources/views/emails/contact_us_was_sent.blade.php
and switching from mailtrap to sendgrid as easy as possible.

I tried something like :

```
\Mail::mailer('smtp')
->to($newContactUs->author_email)
->send( \Mail('emails/contact_us_was_sent', $newContactUs->author_email, '', $subject, $additiveVars, $attachFiles) );
```

But got error as \Mail does not support templates.
Are there something to use support templates for mail Method? Some wrapper?

**Updated:**
Priorly I worked with sendgrid and for this in file config/mail.php I 
wrote all sendgrid parameters.
Now I want to write 2 emeil servers and fi=or this in .env I wrote:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=mailtrip_id
MAIL_PASSWORD=mailtrip_password

SENDGRID_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
SENDGRID_PORT=587
SENDGRID_ENCRYPTION=tls
SENDGRID_USERNAME=sendgrid_user
SENDGRID_PASSWORD=sendgrid_user_password
```

and I remade config/mail.php (I got a sample from):

```
<?php
return [


    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),


    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),


    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),


    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],


    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT'),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'sendgrid' => [
            'transport' => 'sendgrid',
            'host' => env('SENDGRID_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),
            'port' => env('SENDGRID_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('SENDGRID_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('SENDGRID_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('SENDGRID_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

];
```

I am not sure that this config file is valid? Are mail config parameters are read from mailers array ?
Looks like default(mailtrip) mail config is used always. Is it invalid format ?

In my control Ido:

```
        $email_mode= 'live';
//        $email_mode= 'debug';

        if( $email_mode== 'debug' ) {
            \Log::info( '-10 Send to mailtrap ::' );

            \Mail
                ::mailer('smtp')
                ->to('myemail@yahoo.com') // DEBUG
                ->send(new TestEmail);  // 
            \Log::info( '-10 Send to mailtrap AFTER::' );
        }

        // sendgrid
        if( $email_mode== 'live') {
            \Log::info( '-11 Send to sendgrid ::' );
            \Mail
                ::mailer('sendgrid')
                ->to('myemail@yahoo.com') // DEBUG
                ->send(new SendgridMail('emails/contact_us_was_sent', $newContactUs->author_email, '', $subject, $additiveVars, $attachFiles));
            \Log::info( '-11 Send to sendgrid AFTER::' );
        }
```

I check in logs that live flow is run but anyway I got email at mailtrap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found decision with modifying config/mail.php :

```
<?php

return [


    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'sendgrid'),


    'mailers' => [
        'mailtrap' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT'),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'sendgrid' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('SENDGRID_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),
            'port' => env('SENDGRID_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('SENDGRID_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('SENDGRID_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('SENDGRID_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
```

and having 2 groups 'mailtrap' and 'sendgrid'  in .env I wrote in control :

```
\Mail
    ::mailer(true ? 'sendgrid' : 'mailtrap')
    ->to($newContactUs->author_email)
    ->send(new SendgridMail(
        'emails/contact_us_was_sent',
        $newContactUs->author_email, '', $subject,
        $additiveVars,
        $attachFiles)
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you are using \Mail() which is a native php function
see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and try to embed that in a laravel Mailer.

This is not how you should use it, this is really not advised.

Some more detail:
As you write mailables, already you should consider, the Mailable should not define the driver, so it's not encouraged to name it SendGridMailA.. see it as MailA send with Mail::mailer($mailDriver)

See:https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#writing-mailables

Long answer, see this video, explains how to implement multiple mail drivers:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCONO0cwsoI

However it looks like you using it as a debug method. This is not why multiple mail drivers where introduced in laravel 7. It's more like you should use a different driver for bulk mails for example and for password resets...

That makes sense..

For debuging, it more usefull to make the default driver, depend on the APP_DEBUG configuration for example, or introduce an own ENV var, to toggle your production app in debug mode...

Comment: Thanks for help, I tried to follow provided video, but now I always  got email at mailtrap.
Please, look at Updated block